# How to define a key in 'special-mode?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

I would like to have `;` bound to `other-window` in special modes, unless the derived mode overrides the definition. It would be nice to also include modes not strictly deriving from `special-mode` (but defining `'mode-class`), but that's not strictly necessary.

Ideas I've tried/considered:

- Use `global-set-key`: I thought the global keymap would be of lower precedence than major-mode keymaps, so `;` would work in modes that defined it, but instead I just overwrote `self-insert-command`
- Add the keybinding in `special-mode-hook`: It doesn't seem like this hook is actually run, and this misses the `'mode-class` special modes
- Add a keybinding that either calls `other-window` or defers to the major mode. Not sure how I would do this?

Any ideas?

Comment: Just use `define-key` with `special-mode-map`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use `special-mode-map` when possible. When it doesn't work, simply use the corresponding mode map such as `Info-mode-map`.

---

The following (needs `bind-key.el`) might works (I tested in info-mode and help-mode), it uses `bind-key.el`'s `override-global-mode`, which overrides any minor-mode binding of `;`.

```
(defun override-global-mode-semicolon ()
  (interactive)
  (if (eq (get major-mode 'mode-class) 'special)
      (call-interactively 'other-window)
    (let (buf (current-buffer))
      (override-global-mode -1)
      (unwind-protect
          (call-interactively (key-binding ";"))
        (and (buffer-live-p buf)
             (with-current-buffer buf
               (override-global-mode 1)))))))

(bind-key* ";" 'override-global-mode-semicolon)
```

Comment: Sorry should have added this to the ideas considered. This misses all of the special modes defined using `'mode-class` as well as any that don't use `special-mode-map` as their parent keymap.

Comment: @Felipe I see, I added another solution, try it if you want.

Comment: Thanks, this is great! Since I know that the default global binding is `self-insert-command`, I don't need `bind-key` so am just doing `(defun global-semi () (interactive)  (if (eq (get major-mode 'mode-class) 'special)
      (call-interactively 'other-window) (call-interactively 'self-insert-command)))` which I then `global-set-key` on `";"`.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC you're just looking for:

```
(define-key special-mode-map ";" #'other-window)
```

And for those other modes which don't (yet) derive from `special-mode`, you'll have to do something like

```
(add-hook '<foo>-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key ";" #'other-window)))
```

tho I'd advise you to report those modes via `M-x report-emacs-bug` if you think they should derive from `special-mode`.